# Copy Paste not working

Tags: 12.10, unity, shortcut-keys, clipboard

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on my machine (not in VirtualBox). It has been there for about two years (I upgraded from 11.04). I am using the default Unity user interface.

Today copy/paste just stopped working! In NetBeans, Gedit, Firefox, etc. it also doesn't work neither with the keyboard nor with the mouse. When I copy some text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or right-click -> Copy), I still have the **Paste** mouse menu item disabled.

However, in the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> work well, while <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, pretty strange though! I had a **wine** application running, closing it results in copy/paste working again, when I open the application again, copy/paste stops working!

Comment: I added your question in this answer to your original question, so now you should edit your answer and remove the question from it, so that your answer won't get deleted by someone who mistakenly thinks it's a question instead of an answer (which it is, of course!).